# Javascript To Do List issue

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a To Do List for a project since I've just started learning JavaScript. Here's the code.

```js
function newElement() {
  var inputval = document.getElementById('inputnewlist').value;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var lichild = document.createTextNode('inputval');

  li.appendchild('lichild');
  if (inputval === '') {
    alert('you must put something in the textbox!');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mylist').appendchild('li');
  }
  document.getElementById('inputnewlist').value = "";
}

document.getElementsByClassName('addbutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  newElement();
});
```

```html
<div id="formcontainer">
  <h2 class="title"> To Do List </h2>
  <label for="inputnewlist"> Add To List</label>
  <input type="text" name="inputnewlist" id="inputnewlist" placeholder="Add thing to do..">
  <button class="addbutton">Add</button>
</div>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li> hi hehe <span class="exit"> x </span></li>
</ul>
```

The issue is that the button does nothing at all. I already tried using onclick instead of eventlistener but nothing changed. What's wrong with it? I can't see why it won't work to be honest.
I hope you guys can help!

Comment: "The issue is that the button does nothing at all." What is the button *supposed to do*?

Comment: `"Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function"`

Comment: sorry for the lack of explanation, the button is supposed to get the value of the input, and create a li inside the ul, and place the input value inside the li. Afterwards, it should clear out the input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's *a lot* wrong here.  But the main issue is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a *collection* rather than a single element.  So you'll need to loop over that collection to interact with the elements:

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('addbutton');
for (let b of buttons) {
  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newElement();
  });
}
```

Aside from that, you have a variety of typos where you're using incorrect function names (JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `appendchild` should be `appendChild`) and using strings where you meant to use variables (`'li'` instead of `li`, `'lichild'` instead of `lichild`).

I suspect you meant to write this:

```js
function newElement() {
  var inputval = document.getElementById('inputnewlist').value;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var lichild = document.createTextNode(inputval);

  li.appendChild(lichild);
  if (inputval === '') {
    alert('you must put something in the textbox!');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mylist').appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById('inputnewlist').value = "";
}

let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('addbutton');
for (let b of buttons) {
  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
     newElement();
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="formcontainer">
  <h2 class="title"> To Do List </h2>
  <label for="inputnewlist"> Add To List</label>
  <input type="text" name="inputnewlist" id="inputnewlist" placeholder="Add thing to do..">
  <button class="addbutton">Add</button>
</div>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li> hi hehe <span class="exit"> x </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh, thanks for pointing those out- Must have been losing my focus. Thank You for the complete explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, you want to access the first element in the collection

change

```
document.getElementsByClassName('addbutton').addEventListener(...)
```

to

```
document.getElementsByClassName('addbutton')[0].addEventListener(...)
```

or you could use `querySelector` which returns the first matching element

```
document.querySelector('.addbutton').addEventListener(...)
```